# Request for ASPX Page Returns Blank Document

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I have an older web forms application running on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS Version 6.1 or 7.5 (depending on where in the about window you look.) When I add a new page to this web application and hit it, it returns a blank document. All content, including static text has been stripped from it. Fiddler shows a 200 status code. Nothing appears to be logged about it, assuming the Event Viewer is the only place to look.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this issue?

Incidentally, the page works fine running through Visual Studio.

Comment: What is the raw response in fiddler ? Is it Empty? Also are you trying locally on the same machine or remotely ? How about static files?

Comment: Fiddler response comes back and says no response body. I'm trying to hit a page on a QA server and getting this result. I believe I've narrowed it down somewhat. I think an Exception is happening and our logging (Elmah) may be stuck in a loop. This page worked on my local machine, incidentally.